# Is there any equivalent in OpenCV to scikit-image's clear_borders function?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am working on a program that isolates specific small objects in an image.  I am able to isolate the objects of interest in most cases, but get fouled up occasionally by noise at the image borders.

**Skimage** has a nifty tool (`skimage.segmentation.clear_borders`) for fixing this but, since I am going to ultimately have to migrate large chunks of this code to C++, I want to keep everything pure **OpenCV** if I can.

OpenCV doesn't seem to have anything like `clear_borders` though, so I was looking for suggestions as to a simple way to do this in openCV.

Comment: You can use `cv2.copyMakeBorder()` to put an artificial buffer around the edges so that nothing touches the edges then strip it back off later.

Comment: That worked well enough.  Thanks.  It still isn't *quite* what I'm looking for, since I don't always know how big objects on the border will be, and would rather just clear out anything that touches the border regardless of size, but, for now, it definitely does the job.  :)